# Moving multiple folders with batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file to update our paperwork folders for the new year, and I can't find a way to make this a one-click operation. I've got around a hundred folders all containing the following folders:

1. 2020
2. Archive

   - 2018
   - 2019

I need to move the 2020 folder (and all its contents) to the archive and create a new 2021 folder in its place. I'm using robocopy to do this in each individual folder, but I haven't been able to find a way to have the script go to the next folder when it's done. Making things more complicated, the top-level folders have no set naming structure.

Edit: adding my code

```
@ECHO OFF
MKDIR 2021
ROBOCOPY /MOVE /S /E 2020 "Previous Years\2020" /MT:32
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.
SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /s /ad "%sourcedir%\2020" '
 ) DO (
 MD "%%~dpa2021" >NUL 2>nul
 MD "%%~dpaArchive" >NUL 2>nul
 MOVE "%%a" "%%~dpaArchive\" >NUL 2>nul
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Find all of the `2020` directories located below `sourcedir`. Make the `2021` and `Archive` directories, suppressing error messages should those directories alreay exist. Move the `2020` directory into the archive.

I'd suggest you test this routine on a subtree-copy, but that's just the Irish in me.

(And strictly, this question is off-topic since you've provided no code of your own. But - hey, it's a new year and boy, am I bored...)

Comment: Awesome, worked like a champ in my test directory! Now to put it to work on the real deal. thanks for the heads up about the code, edited my original to comply